# Using "Layout Update XML" to add a block to the sidebar

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, static-block

When I create a new page in Magento 2 using the "two columns with left bar" layout it by default puts the wishlist in there.

Using the "layout update XML" in the design options tab I can remove that using this:

```
<referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

What I also want to do is replace it with my own static block. I thought something like the following would do the trick but it does not. Can someone help?

```
<container name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test" />
</container>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To reference a container you need to use `referenceContainer` as opposite to `referenceBlock` to reference a block.

The `container` tag is used to create a container as the `block` tag is used to create a block.

In your case, the right code would be:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

This is assuming your cms block id is `test`, you'll need to replace that value in case it is different

Comment: Is it's necessary to put block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test">  ??

Comment: @Arunendra yes it is required

Comment: Thank you all for the solution! Does anyone know if it is possible to add a css class / div wrapper to the block using XML? Or is the best way to just wrap the contents of the block in a div manually?

Comment: @user1837290 please ask a different question for that, it'll have a better visibility and you'll get help easily

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism thank you, will do :)

Comment: weird. This works on one of my installs, but it doesnt work on the other! SHM!

Answer (score 2):

It should work like this

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
           <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```