# Magento 2.2 removing horizontal menu from front page only

Tags: magento2, topmenu

i am trying the following code :

`<referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <referenceBlock name="main_menu" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>`

in the DESIGN TAB > Layout Update XML in my page.
but its not working.

my block's id is > 89
identifier is > main_menu
and title is > Home 01- main menu.
what else could i do to make this code work.
basically, i want to remove this block from the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**just hide it on home page.**

check your body tag classes, there will be some unique class on home page body tag.

```
<body class="cms-home cms-index-index" >

</body>
```

by css you can hide it on only home page :)

Comment: can you tell me how and where to hide it?
in which file?

Comment: can you give some html snippet from that block, which you want to hide?

Comment: <div class="main-menu menu-style-2">{{widget type="CleverSoft\CleverMegaMenus\Block\Widget\Megamenu" menu="main_menu"}}</div>
<div class="zoo-customer-service text-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
<p>Customer Service: <span style="font-weight: 600;"> (+xx) xxx- 7200-151</span></p>
</div>

thats the html used in this block

Comment: add in custom.css ,                                                                                   
              body.cms-home div.main-menu.menu-style-2{display:none}

Comment: i am anxiously waiting for your humble suggestion and solutions

Comment: is it work for you?

Comment: it worked for me very well

Comment: welcome laiba :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try not to reference the Container?

As I see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110747/using-layout-update-xml-to-add-a-block-to-the-sidebar), a friend has remove the wishlist sidebar only with Block's reference.

Comment: yes @christoforos i've tried it and doing this shows me the following error

Comment: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1

Comment: Have you enable path hints (Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront) and block hints (Add Block Names to Hints) in the admin interface?

You will find them here: Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug

Comment: maybe not. can you guid me how can i enable that setting?

Comment: I edit the comment. Check in the path I add.

Comment: i enabled all those but nothing changed :(